# Relations in Discrete Math/ tables

Tags: relations

Does anyone know how to make this table? I can do a table with normal values but the $x^2$ throws me off.

'Write the relation as a table, the relation $\mathbb{Z}$ on $\{1,2,3,4\}$ by $(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}$ if $x^2\geq y$.'

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{matrix}
xRy & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & T & F & F & F \\
2 & T & T & T & T \\
3 & T & T & T & T \\
4 & T & T & T & T
\end{matrix}$$

You simply need to evaluate the truth value of each relation.  $2R1\iff 2^2\geq1$, so $2R1$ is true.  Comment if you have questions, there's nothing complicated about this.

Comment: This is a truth table, the text example is asking for a relation as a table, with the prior example having the table listing coordinate pairs. So I'm not sure if what you have is what its asking for, or a table of coordinates? "Write the relation as a table" is all it says.

Comment: The truth table is equivalent, as $x$ is related to $y$ whenever $xRy$ is true.  If you wanted, you could rewrite the table as follows, which may be closer to what you're looking for:

$$\begin{matrix}
(1,1) &  &  &  \\
(2,1) & (2,2) & (2,3) & (2,4) \\
(3,1) & (3,2) & (3,3) & (3,4) \\
(4,1) & (4,2) & (4,3) & (4,4) \\
\end{matrix}$$

Comment: ty this makes sense now much appreciated!